# Load more button wordpress posts page

Tags: wordpress

Hola necesito implementar un load more para cargar más posts en un template de wordpress, ya he intentado varios metodos pero ninguno funciona correctamente

```
<section id="blog">
            <div class="content-box">
                <?php
                $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args = array(
                'category_name' => '',
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'paged' => $paged
                 );
                $query = new WP_Query($args);

                if($query->have_posts()):
                    while($query->have_posts()):
                         $query->the_post();
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format());
                    endwhile;
                endif;
                ?>
            </div>

        </section><!--/#blog-->
```

Comment: ¿Al ejecutar este código qué sucede?, por favor [edit] tu pregunta con mas detalles.

Comment: Las versiones más recientes de Wordpress incluyen plantillas con opciones para "scroll infinito" y  "cargar más". ¿Tienes tu Wordpress actualizado?, basta con revisar las plantillas actuales para ver cómo lo hacen y aplicarlo en tu proyecto.